# using PowerApps how to mass update 1% to 10% records in SharePoint list that has 20k+ records in total

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

from Power Apps, how could I replace few items values on SharePoint list which has 20K+ items?
I tried:

```
updateif(sourcename, a=dd.SelectedText.Value, {a:dd_1.SelectedText.Value})
```

Comment: Have you considered that PowerApps may be the wrong tool for this kind of job?

Comment: thanks. so could this be done using PowerApps or what could I do? Client has developed this App and is asking my help resolving this issue which he is finding challenging but I am not able to find quick solution either. what could be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it sounds like this is not a performance question or functionality ask. If this is for just a one time bulk data update, you can use any ETL package to run the job for batch updates.

You can use Azure data factory, SSIS package, Scribe, SQL job, or console app hitting SP web api. It really depends on the source/destination and skillset of the team.

Comment: I really appreciate your guidance and I agree with you. however client seem to prefer maximum work done using power platform products only. the story is written with all such details

Comment: @RajuChoudhari then use Power Automate to fetch all the records to be updated and iterate through the list for updating them

Comment: correct that is exactly what I am trying to do but what is the code for that? how to do that? I created another list with distinct values from particular column and created two drop downs. now values selected in first drop down needs to be replaced with values from second dropdown. but this has to be done in orginal sharepoint list which has many many records which needs to be updated.

Comment: and No, this is not one time requirement. The app will be used by user admin. and when user changes parent from old to new, all child records he wants to see updated with new parent.

Comment: @RajuChoudhari PowerApp is different from Power Automate(Flow), you never mentioned Flow in question. So from canvas PowerApp you trigger a Power Automate flow  to pass params,query and update these records in Flow. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/PowerApp-Button-pass-2-seperate-parameters-to-a-Flow-for/td-p/90684

Comment: You'd need to do this in batches of 500 items, though, since neither PowerApps nor Power Automate can handle more items at any one time. Might be worth trying to explain to the customer that the approach is wrong for the purpose, and therefore you will be facing almost insurmountable challenges. Just because the client has decided that they will use a hammer for everything, does not mean that it can turn a screw.

Comment: @ArunVinoth I am not sure if I mentioned Flow somewhere? but that is ok too. I just do not know how to do this,  what could be code for that in PowerApps and in Flow?

Comment: @teylyn I agree there could be challenges on this path but the client ask seems simple business requirement, is there a way to generate simple SQL update statement and pass it to SharePoint list from PowerApps? Client thinks this is one liner SQL update statement and I have equipped you with most powerful toolset. how could I answer this?